# Calculating the number of states in power of 10's

Tags: logarithms

This is part of a problem that was assigned to me. It might seem elementary, but I need a hint on how to start this problem.

I have 10 billion bits that can either be on or off at any time.

Assuming that $$2^{10} \approx 10^3  $$

Calculate the number of possible states of the brain in powers of 10.

Comment: Let's start with a simpler problem. Suppose you have 17 bits. How many possible states are there?

Comment: wouldn't it be 2^17 states?

Comment: Yes! So, now you can write down how many states with 10 billion bits, and then you have to turn that into a power of 10. Can you do that? or at least get started on doing that?

Comment: Ya I think I got the idea now! I was way over thinking this problem. thx!

Comment: You should post your answer and accept it.  For us, it gets an answer to the question.  For you, it gets a check on your answer.  We all win.

Comment: Since I'm below 10 rep can't post own question for 7 hours - -